Wix how to redirect to home page from function?
I have a problem, from Wix I redirect the page to third party, after third party done process, it will post the data back to wix (callback). at first the callback URL I set is the home page, but it show error 403 because of Wix can't direct display the page when the call is POST method.
so I trying using http-function to handle the POST back and try to redirect to main page, but some how it still have problem.
any idea on how I can display the home page when the third party call back with POST method ? (I no need to handle the post data)

You have the right idea. You just need to build the redirect response properly. Try something like this:
import { response } from 'wix-http-functions';

export function post_redirect(request) {
   return response({
       "headers": {
           'Location': 'https://yoursite.com'
       },
       "status": 302
   });
}

